# I want to enter a value in an Entry, press a Button and save that value in a var and create a .txt with that value but it's not working

Tags: python, tkinter

and first of all, excuse me if I write many mistakes in my text, English is not my first language, thanks in advance. Secondly, I'm new with Python and Tkinter, I have watched a few youtube videos and I'm following some tutorials to do this.

I'm trying to create a software that it is supposed to receive a value that I enter through an Entry after I press a button to generate it, save that value in a variable and generate a new document.txt with the value I introduced.

I have tried changing the line with:
- idcheck=StringVar() to idcheck = str(), but in console it says: AttributeError: 'str'object has no attribute 'get'.

This is the code, I have tried to reduce at maximum the amount of code so you can try to execute and check what's happening.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def funcion():
    print("ID: ", idcheck.get()) #To make sure that the value I'm entering is correct

window.title("app") 
Label(window, text="ID").grid(padx=10 ,pady=10, row=0, column=0)

idcheck = StringVar() #this is giving me troubles when I do next step (.write says it must be str() not StringVar()

Entry(window, textvariable=idcheck, width=30).grid(padx=5, row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W)
Button(window, text="Generate", width=30, command=funcion).grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=E+W)

idchecklist = open("document.txt","w")
idchecklist.write(idcheck.get())
idchecklist.close()

window.mainloop()
```

I expect to get the value I'm introducing in the Entry in a new document but the actual output is creating a document.txt but it is empty (I don't know how to get this value).

What else could I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The logic to write to a file is outside the function. When you execute the python program it creates the file document.txt even before user clicks on Generate button and `idecheck` is empty at that point which is why the file is empty. You could move this logic when user clicks on Generate button as below

```
def funcion():
    print("ID: ", idcheck.get())  # To make sure that the value I'm entering is correct
    idchecklist = open("document.txt", "w")
    idchecklist.write(idcheck.get())
    idchecklist.close()
```

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much, that worked! As simple as moving some code.